# How do I get all h1,h2,h3 etc elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I want to write something like this in javascript:

```
var all_headings = document.getElementsByTagName("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6");
```

`all_headings` would then be a list of all elements that are `h1` or `h2` or `h3`...  And in the order that they appear in the document, of course.

How do I do it?

Comment: you can allways do a separate getElementsByTagName and merge the arrays

Comment: @Emil: But you won't be able to get the order right.

Comment: @Emil - no you can't it won't preserve order.

Comment: Ha, missed that in the post. My bad! ^^

Comment: @Daniel: If DOM selection is the only thing desired, then Sizzle would make more sense.

Comment: Do you want this to work in a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

With modern browsers you can do

```
document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
```

Or you could get cross-browser compatibility by using jQuery:

```
$("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
```

Comment: querySelectorAll doesn't return a live list like getElementsByTagName.  Does the jquery version return a live list?

Comment: A live list is a series of pointers into the document that you can modify.  For example, each element of the output of querySelectorAll() has .parent = null.  Compare with getElementsByTagName where the elements have .parent set.

Comment: Oh. Then yes, with jQuery you get the elements with all their document properties and positions set correctly.

Comment: .parentElement attributes exist for querySelectorAll results now

Comment: @Eyal You can use `Array.from()` to make a usable array.

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(...))`

Answer (score 22):

If you are using jQuery you can use

```
$(":header")
```

example from jQuery documentation

```
<script>$(":header").css({ background:'#CCC', color:'blue' });</script>
```

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/header-selector/)

Comment: did not know about this! Thanks for the shortcut

Answer (score 9):

If you're just needing some cross-browser DOM selection, there's no need to load jQuery.

Just load [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) instead. It's the selector engine that jQuery uses.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/77bMG/

```
var headings = Sizzle('h1,h2,h3');

for( var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++ ) {
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(i + ' is ' + headings[i].innerHTML);
}
```

---

Or without any library code, you can walk the DOM, and push the headings into an Array.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/77bMG/1/

```
var headings = [];

var tag_names = {
    h1:1,
    h2:1,
    h3:1,
    h4:1,
    h5:1,
    h6:1
};

function walk( root ) {
    if( root.nodeType === 1 && root.nodeName !== 'script' ) {
        if( tag_names.hasOwnProperty(root.nodeName.toLowerCase()) ) {
            headings.push( root );
        } else {
            for( var i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
                walk( root.childNodes[i] );
            }
        }
    }
}

walk( document.body );

for( var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++ ) {
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(i + ' is ' + headings[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

QuentinUK's is the best answer here, as it is the /only/ one that answers the question by providing a solution using only JavaScript with no libraries.

```
for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h'+i);
    for (j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
        headers[j].className = 'h';
    }
}
var headers = document.getElementsByClassName('h');
for (i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].innerHTML += ' '+i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need jQuery for something simple; try his:

```
var tags = [ "h1","h2","h3" ];
var all_headings = [];

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    all_headings = all_headings.concat(document.getElementsByTagName(tags[i]));
```

Comment: You're creating an Array that holds 3 NodeLists. Might as well just use `.push()` instead of `.concat()`.

Comment: Doesnt concat merge the result of getElementsByTagName into all_headings? I havent really tested it.

Comment: @TJHeuvel: Unfortunately, no. You could do something like this in your `for` statement, but it still won't maintain the order in the document as required in the question, and it won't work in IE8 and lower. `all_headings.push.apply(all_headings, all_headings.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tags[i])));`

Answer (score 2):

Function without jQuery and document.querySelectorAll

```
function get_all_h(document) {
    var arr = [];
    if (!document) return arr;
    var all_el = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0, n = all_el.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (/^h\d{1}$/gi.test(all_el[i].nodeName)) {
            arr.push(all_el[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them a common class name then use `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE (I think only IE9 has it).

Comment: These is no mention of either old versions of IE or anything about a Chrome extension in the question.